# matplotlib add artist not showing labels on legend

Tags: matplotlib, legend, subplot

this is my first question here and one probably very simple, however I tried to fix any mistake and look more info but with no success, I am new to programming graphs using matplotlib, could anyone help me out? thank you in advance

The goal of the program was to graphic a circle and a label, but label was not appearing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r',label='Men')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 2, color='r',label='Men')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps use `ax.add_patch(circle1)`.

Comment: Thank you it was really useful, appreciated BigBen and thanks a lot for the thoughtful explanation WVJoe

Comment: Done, it was really helpful, thank you. It seems i cannot upvote though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, you are only plotting the first circle (with radius 0.2). You never call the second circle, so it does not show up. Not sure what you are going for here. However, [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) is correct, just use `ax.add_patch(circle1)` instead and it will show with the labels. With this minor change, your plot will look like this:

[image: Plot 1]

You would also want to set x and y axis limits in order to see the entire circle. This code below will allow you to see both circles in full with different labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r',label='Small Red',zorder=2)
circle2 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 2, color='b',label='Big Blue',zorder=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xlim([-3,3])
ax.set_ylim([-3,3])
plt.show()
```

And your plot will look like this:

[image: Plot 2]

The zorder argument will decide which object shows up in front of the other. They will appear front-to-back in descending order.